# How to iterate over a complex associative array?

Tags: php, foreach

I'm working with the following array.

```
Array
(
[device_id] => 432552343242
[host_name] => computer
[serial_number] => 32525243
[manufacturer] => HP
[model] => ProLiant BL460c Gen9
[locations] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => New York
            )

    )

[cpu_count] => 1
[core_count] => 6
[is_virtual] => 
[operating_system] => Array
    (
        [version] => 6.6 Santiago
        [product] => Array
            (
                [vendor] => Varied
                [description] => ProductAdapter for handling various Unix or 
Linux based Operating Systems (HP-UX, AIX, Solaris, Ubuntu, etc...)
                [name] => Unix Operating Systems
            )

        [name] => Linux Server
    )

[users] => mydomain.com/users
[applications] => mydomain.com/applications
[qualified_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name_type] => UnixName
                [name] => cbc.com
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name_type] => DNSFQDN
                [name] => abc.com
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name_type] => DNSDomain
                [name] => bbc.com
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [name_type] => OriginalHostname
                [name] => cnn.com
            )

    )
)
```

When I try to loop through the array in order to insert it into a database I get 13 entries.

Here is my code.

```
$array = json_decode($result, true);
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
$hostname = $array['locations'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (Hostname) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $hostname);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
```

I know why its adding it 13 teams. Its looping through each index in the array and inserting the hostname for each one. How can I just get it to insert it ones? Do I have to create a for statement? Or a foreach within a foreach? Any help would be appreciated? Newbie here.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping as many times as you have indexes in your biggest array, **BUT** you don't use `$key` and `$value`. Your code is exactly doing what you said to him to do:

- for each value -> so 13 loop

  - get the `$array['location']` value
  - insert it into your database
- end of your foreach

If you just want to insert your `$array['locations']`, why are you using a `foreach` ?
You are inserting just one value, and you know it's index, so you don't really need to use a `foreach`

#### With a `foreach` you can do:

```
$array = json_decode($result, true);
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    if ($key === "location")
    {
        //$hostname = $array['locations'];
        $hostname = $value;

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (Hostname) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $hostname);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

But there is no real need.

#### I would more write it like that:

```
$array = json_decode($result, true);
$hostname = $array['location'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (Hostname) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $hostname);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

## [EDIT]

If you want to loop to insert differents elements of your array, you should use the `$key` and `$value` variables.

```
$array = json_decode($result, true);
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    if ($key === "location")
    {
        $hostname = $value; //contains $array['location']

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (Hostname) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $hostname);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    } else if ($key === 'device_id')
    {
        $devide_id= $value; //contains $array['device_id']

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (DeviceId) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $devide_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    } else if ($key === 'device_id')
    {
        $devide_id= $value; //contains $array['device_id']

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (DeviceId) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $devide_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    } else if ($key === 'device_id')
    {
        $devide_id= $value; //contains $array['device_id']

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (DeviceId) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $devide_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    } else if ($key === 'device_id')
    {
        $devide_id= $value; //contains $array['device_id']

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (DeviceId) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $devide_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    } else if ($key === '...')
    {
        //etc
    }
}
```

But if you know exactly the keys of your values in your array, I would do it more like that:

```
$hostname  = $array['location'];
$devide_id = $array['device_id'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (Hostname) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $hostname);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (DeviceId) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $devide_id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: omg. That's so obvious. Thank you. The reason I was thinking a foreach statement was necessary was because I was working with a large multidimensional array before. Got a bit of tunnel vision. Thanks again.